# OpenGL: Greyscale texture data layout doesn't match when the dimensions aren't divisible by 4

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

If I create a greyscale texture with dimensions that aren’t divisible by 4, the layout doesn't match the given data. If I make the texture RGBA, everything works. What’s going on? Is openGL internally packing the data into RGBA format?

`width=16`:

[image]

`width=15`:

[image]

```
int width = 15;
unsigned char* localBuffer = new unsigned char[width*width];

glGenTextures(1, &textureObjID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjID);

for (int i = 0; i < width*width; i++)
{
    float x = (i % width) / (float)width;
    localBuffer[i] = x * 255;
}

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, width, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, localBuffer);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned 4 bytes.

This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4.

Since the image has 1 (RED) color channel, and is tightly packed the start of a row of the image is aligned to 4 bytes if `width=16`, but it is not aligned to 4 bytes if `width=15`.

Change the the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter to 1, before specifying the two-dimensional texture image (`glTexImage2D`):

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, width, 
             0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, localBuffer);
```

Since that is missed, this cause a shift effect at each line of the image, except if the width of the image is divisible by 4.
When the format of the image is changed to `GL_RGBA`, the the size of single pixel is 4, so the size of a line (in bytes) is divisible by 4 in any case.